# Keyboard freezing in physical devices when adding input to TextField

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have built a commenting functionality thats basically taking a textfield input and appending it to a list of comments.

**The problem is that I can input a few times but always, the keyboard and eventually the app freezes while i'm typing and I don't know how because when I test on the simulator, it works as expected.**

The code is attached below:

```
@State var commentText = ""
TextField ("", text: $commentText, prompt: Text("Say Something...").foregroundColor(.white).font(Font.system(size: 12)))
    .autocapitalization(.none)
    .disableAutocorrection(true)
    .padding(.horizontal)
    .foregroundColor(.white).font(Font.system(size: 12))
    .frame(width: 160, height: 38)
    .cornerRadius(20)
    .overlay(
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20).stroke(.white, lineWidth: 2)
    )
    .onSubmit {
        if commentText != "" {
                                                
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {
                UpdateDB().updateComments(listingID: String(describing: retrievedShow["listings"]!), comment: commentText, username: userName) { response in
                    if response == "Comment added successfully" {
                        commentText = ""
                        withAnimation(.easeOut(duration: 0.5)) {
                            proxy.scrollTo(noOfComments, anchor: .bottom)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I believe the error is not related to any of my database read-write operations as i've tried not inserting to the database and just entering inputs but it still freezes.

I've also tried disabling autocorrection as I thought it might have been a performance issue on the device's side but no luck.

I expect to be able to comment normally as a user without my app crashing.

Comment: First, comment out `onSubmit`. Second, check that are there any other places that cause ui blocked. Third, create an empty project and put only your TextField.

Comment: I have tried with a button instead of onSubmit, still the same issue

Comment: If you can do it a few times and then it freezes you likely have a leak somewhere, google “memory leaks” you’ll find lots of articles on how to diagnose.